# How to track the scroll event with jQuery Mobile, when I come back from a page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to track the scroll event with jQuery, and it works when the page loads, but when I come back from other page, the scroll event is not fired.

I'm making and app with jQuery Mobile, I tried without the jQueryMobile library and works perfectly.

I have an html file per page.

This is a sample:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="height:200%;">
    <div data-role="page" id="page">
        <a href="http://google.com">link</a>
    </div>
        <script>
            //$(document).on("pageinit", "#page", function(event) {
            $(function(){
                $(window).on('scroll', function(){
                    console.log('scroll');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I scroll the page in the first load, it shows in the console "scroll", but when I click the link and I come back to the page, when I scroll the page nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

try using .bind, and bind it to html and body:

```
$('html, body').bind('scroll', function(){
     console.log('scroll');
     });
```